# Return the index from ordinal position pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have searched for this question but cannot find what I am sure to be a simple answer.

I have a dataframe,

```
data
Out[77]: 
                Energy Supply  ...  Pop Estimate
Country                            ...              
United States        9.083800e+10  ...  2.597967e+13
China                1.271910e+11  ...  1.182876e+13
Russian Federation   3.070900e+10  ...  6.571726e+12
Canada               1.043100e+10  ...  3.087576e+12
```

I want to return the string "Russian Federation" as the 3rd highest population estimate. How  do I return the index instead of the value?

I can return the entire series with,

```
data["Pop Estimate"]
```

and I can index the value with

```
data["Pop Estimate"][2]
```

and have tried to use techniques such as transpose, .index,

```
data.index("Pop Estimate")
```

to access the index but I cannot seem to get the return value that I need. Surely this is a very simple question?

Any help will great, thanks!

Joe

Comment: how are you returning the country with the 3rd highest est?

Comment: That is my question, I don't know how to return the index instead of the value. It could be clearer in my Q so I edited it.

Comment: _i want to return the string "Russian Federation" as the 3rd highest population estimate. How do I return the index instead of the value?_ ah i thought you had gotten the value already you could try `df['Pop Estimate'].nlargest(3).tail(1)`

Comment: For whoever wants to try with the given data: data = pandas.DataFrame(data=[["United States",      9.0838e+10, 2.5980e+13], 
                              ["China",              1.2719e+11, 1.1829e+13],
                              ["Russian Federation", 3.0709e+10, 6.5717e+12],
                              ["Canada",             1.0431e+10, 3.0876e+12],
                             ],
                        columns=["Country", "Energy Supply", "Pop Estimate"],
                       ).set_index("Country")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative could be:

```
data.sort_values("Pop Estimate",ascending=False).iloc[2,:].name
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you do .iloc[2,:] instead of simply .iloc[2] (which I would have suggested with my equivalent solution now, if I wouldn't have been too slow copying the content of the DataFrame to see if it works ;-) )?

Answer (score 0):

Give index to each "Pop Estimate" and order by value of "Pop Estimate".

for example

[[2.597967e+13, 0], [1.182876e+13, 1], [6.571726e+12, 2], [3.087576e+12,3]]

=>

[[2.597967e+13, 0], [1.182876e+13, 1], [6.571726e+12, 2], [3.087576e+12,3]]

(In your case, it look likes already ordered)

If ordering is finished, then you can find index `i` easily.
And you can find row name by this code.

```
dfObj.index.values[i]
```